# Position changing after rotation processing

Tags: user-interface, rotation, processing, translation

I am working on a tic-tac-toe game in my computer science class using processing-java. In my program, on the far right side I have a status bar that states which player's turn it is, who won, and who lost. This status bar is also placed vertically, so in my code I am rotating it and although it is rotating properly, it is causing another problem. The status bar appears in a certain area on the game screen, but after one X or O is placed, it moves spots and I am unsure of how to fix this. After another piece is placed, it moves a second time, then a third and then finalizes its place in an area I do not want it to be. This is my code regarding the text and rotation.

```
void updateStatus(String status) { // function to update the status message
  fill(0);
  rect(statusX, sbh, width, height-1);
  stroke(#FFFFFF);
  strokeWeight(4);
  line(statusX, sbh, statusX, screenH); // Status line
  fill(255);

  String fullStatus = "It is player "+status+"'s turn";
  //String fullStatus = "It is player X's turn";
  float statusTxtX = width*15/16, statusTxtY = height*2.5/7;

  pushMatrix();
  translate(statusTxtX, statusTxtY);
  rotate(HALF_PI);
  textSize(55);
  textFont(mainFont);
  text(fullStatus, 0, 0);
  //textDraw(status, mainFont, height, 255, CENTER, CENTER, statusX, height*3/12, width, height*1/2);
  popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you also use translate() when drawing X / O ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my code is in this github repo,https://github.com/Malrayess/Prototyping-Tik-Tac-Toe

Comment: @J.D., I do not translate my code when drawing X / O, I only translate and rotate when working with my status bar, this is because the status bar is vertical. For more information please visit my github repo., https://github.com/Malrayess/Prototyping-Tik-Tac-Toe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with text-aligns. There is one in the placing() function and one in the textDraw() function. When you disable those the text stays in the same location. However, this will mess up the X's and O's, so you'll need to do some work on tracing where what text-align is set.

As a more general tip (since you're learning): put your first focus on functionality. You could for example build TicTacToe using println() and the numpad as input. When the game mechanics work you can add a nice user interface. Doing both at the same time often makes messy code that is prone to errors that are hard to debug. I bumped into that wall plenty of times myself ;)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried removing the text-align just like you told me to, but when I did so, the status is still moving at least once. When removing the text-align from placing();, it stops moving an extra 2 times. But when I try removing it from placing, I am forced to re-code my placements and text-aligns for all the text I print out(although-yes-it does remove the moving of the status, and keeps it in place.) Is there a way to debug this without throwing the rest of my code off balance?

Comment: You could place a new text-align in from of the `text(fullStatus, 0, 0);`, this will stop it from moving. I suggest you try this, but be aware that, depending on your code, if might influence other text().

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I see what you mean, I do not know how to find a solution for both issues at once, I'll have to find a solution for both soon to make this working properly without altering any other text in the process of doing so. Thank you for your time and efforts in helping me find a solution to this question. If it is possible, I will also be posting another question soon regarding a different issue I do not know much about, or how to solve. If it is possible for you to answer that issue then that would be great, if you can't that is fine as well, thank you for all your help. :)

Comment: I found out the solution, I just needed to align the status and it stopped moving, thank you for your replies and your help! :)